# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in post.php

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, theme-development

Just moved my site to another server and now I get this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/menta/domains/land.menta4u.co.il/wp-includes/post.php on line
>   1172

On the old server all was working perfectly.

I played with it a bit and narrowed it down to my functions.php (it's my own theme) inside it I saw that when I am deleteing the code that initiates the CPT that I created the error disappears. this is the code that initiates the CPT:

```
function testimonials() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'המלצות', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'המלצה', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'המלצות', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'המלצות', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'כל ההמלצות', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'הוסף המלצה חדשה', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'הוסף חדש', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'המלצה חדשה', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'ערוך המלצה', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'עדכן המלצה', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'צפה בהמלצה', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'לא נמצא', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'לא נמצא באשפה', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'testimonial', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Customer Testimonials', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', ),
        'taxonomies'            => false,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-quote',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'testimonial', $args );
}
add_action('init','testimonials',0);
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: you probably were running with error reporting turned off at your old server

Comment: You are right, error reporting was off in old server and that is why I did not see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WordPress 4.5.3, there's a `foreach` in `wp-includes/post.php` [on line 1177](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1172) and no others around it, so I'm guessing this is the one that's triggering the error in your install on line 1172.

This is inside the `register_post_type()` function, and it's looping through the `taxonomies` argument that you're sending through. Well... that you were meant to send through ;)

Your `taxonomies` argument is set to `false`, whereas [register_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) says that **only an array is a suitable value for this argument**. This is why the foreach is erroring out.

So.... with all that said, set `taxonomies` to `array()` if you don't want to have any taxonomies set. Or, you can just leave the argument out completely, and the default of `array()` will apply.

Now you know how to hunt through the error messages to hopefully find the issue in future :) Also, as Mark Kaplun mentioned in the comments, make sure `WP_DEBUG` is set to true in `wp-config.php` on your development server; this way you will catch it from the start (then turn it off on your production server).

Also, it's always a good idea to double check the docs of the function you're calling so you know you're sending through parameters in the correct format. You can start your search at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/

Comment: I've just double checked the two CPTs on a site where I'm seeing this error (in Block Editor screens only) and both have their taxonomies set to `array()`... ...I think there's other reasons why this may show up.

Comment: @TonyDjukic The particular PHP error (invalid argument supplied for foreach) could show up for many reasons. It requires some digging to determine exactly why.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that the errors I'm seeing are actually a result of some hosting issues.  My `foreach()` error is coming from the script-loader.php and the hosting platform is randomly failing to load different scripts/stylesheets on every refresh.  I don't know if it's their new CDN (which can't be turned off without requesting that they do it) or if it's the way they've configured their new cloud platform.